# C# .Net Linq adding new record with identity field

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table of phone numbers that comes from a DB model.  The table has a primary key `phoneId` with an "autoincrement" value.  I need to insert a new row but the model version of the table does not have a nullable `phoneId` member.  How do I specify that the new record should get the next autoincrement/identity number?

I am trying:

```
    var newPhone = new Phone() {
        PhoneId = null,
        PhoneNumber = newNumber
    };

    try {
        pdb.Phones.Add(newPhone);
        pdb.SaveChanges();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("COULD NOT ADD new number: {0}", e.Message);
    }
```

in the model `PhoneId` is a "long" not a "long?".  I don't want to change the model if I don't have to.  If I ever rebuild the model I will lose the change and will probably forget why I needed it.

I tried duplicating the model `Phone` class and setting that version of the `PhoneId` to nullable but then the Linq `.Add()` method balked because it could not convert one to the other.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't assign PhoneID any value at all...omit it. The database will give it its value when you insert it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get back to the office.

Comment: i edited your tags. Please keep in mind that Entity Framework and LINQ-to-SQL are two mutually exclusive technologies. When in doubt, read the tag descriptions.

Comment: could you include what is inside the Phone.cs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to set the field,
The field is initialized when you submit the model

```
var newPhone = new Phone() {
        PhoneNumber = newNumber
    };

try {
    pdb.Phones.Add(newPhone);
    pdb.SaveChanges();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("COULD NOT ADD new number: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The model doesn't have a phoneID because the database will set the value when you insert the record. The primary key cant be nullable also.

[More about Identity fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Look at Example A: in the link above...you will see that they leave out the IDENTITY field.

```
 var newPhone = new Phone(); 
 newPhone.PhoneNumber = newNumber;

 try 
 {
    pdb.Phones.Add(newPhone);
    pdb.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception e) 
 {
    Console.WriteLine("COULD NOT ADD new number: {0}", e.Message);
 }
```